# Background image breaking only on one page

Tags: css, drupal, background-image, background-position

I am having a problem where the background image that is centered aligned, and repeated vertically, is only breaking on the [Latest News page](http://www.pureprint.com/latest-news/).

[image: Screenshot of page]

I can't seem to find why it would be breaking, especially as it is fine on every other page within the site, and there is no section of the page that differs in sizes etc.

I have used firebug to inspect all aspects of the page but still can't find what is causing the problem, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have checked the page in FF, Chrome and IE8 and cannot see any problem with the page. Can you attach a screenshot to show what problem you mean?

Comment: I have the same problem on FF and Chrome. How to you position you image : CSS or JS ?

Comment: I see what you mean, the background image breaks/does not align on that page only (just below the large header image). The only difference I could was the following class in the body tag of that page: section-latest-news. I wasn't able to view the styling associated with that style though. Have you tried removing it to see if it makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the background image is placed twice on the page. Since you use one that's 2000 x 2000, the cut comes to early on the page, to make it a problem with the top/bottom not fitting.

Another thing is that the top/bottom doesn't fit, so you will get that cut for all pages longer than 2000 px, which is the reason for the second cut on the page. You should instead use a much smaller image, like 10-40 px high, that will fit when repeated. That will give your users a faster page speed. It might also fix the problem, or help you track down the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think the page is to long for one image, the it repeat.

But, look at you image, it seem that the top of image is'nt correctly connected with the bottom. (Y know what I mean?).